Oracle PLPDF checkbox value issue
One of my Oracle apex region, want to print in PDF format using PLPDF libraries.
Region includes all type of section text field, checkbox, select list component etc. During print all component are displaying with their respecting values but only having problem with checkbox, the boxes are showing with no values (i.e. no tick mark).
How to solve this? Passing dynamic value of checkbox bases on condition will tick or untick like flag value Yes then tick else not.
I tried this way but instead of Tick mark '✔' its showing ‘?’
plpdf.printcell2(P_W=>4, P_H=>5, P_TXT=>'✔', P_BORDER=>'1', P_LN=>0, P_CLIPPING=>1);

My expectation is when I will do print if checkbox ticked then as is it should print. No blank box.
enter image description here

The checkbox rendering issue in PLPDF likely due to font encoding limitations and symbol handling. When using characters like '✔', PLPDF may not properly encode these special symbols. Maybe you can try using ZapfDingbats font, or create custom checkbox symbols using vector graphics. Alternatively, consider using PDF generation APIs like pagesnap.co which use browser-based rendering that can capture HTML/CSS styling better.
